# Routing custom key in XML

Tags: symfony

I have my routes file as XML format. I want to have some custom key for each route. Something like:

```
<route id="my.index" path="/">
    <default key="_controller">TestBundle:Test:indexAction</default>
    <custom_key>value</custom_key>
    <custom_array_key>
        <custom_key>value<custom_key>
    </custom_array_key>
</route>
```

How can I do it? Thank for all your help...

Comment: What would this result in ? Are you trying to pass static arguments to your method ?

Comment: Yes, and I want to handle these values by $request object in Controller